# In Haskell, Why (a -> a) type can accept k (a ->a) type as paramter?

Tags: haskell

I am learn haskell by doing fp-course's exercise (https://github.com/system-f/fp-course)

When filling `(*>)` in `Application.hs`. I cannot understance the answer as follow.

```
-- | Apply, discarding the value of the first argument.
-- Pronounced, right apply.
--
-- >>> (1 :. 2 :. 3 :. Nil) *> (4 :. 5 :. 6 :. Nil)
-- [4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6]
--
-- >>> (1 :. 2 :. Nil) *> (4 :. 5 :. 6 :. Nil)
-- [4,5,6,4,5,6]
--
-- >>> (1 :. 2 :. 3 :. Nil) *> (4 :. 5 :. Nil)
-- [4,5,4,5,4,5]
--
-- >>> Full 7 *> Full 8
-- Full 8
--
-- prop> \a b c x y z -> (a :. b :. c :. Nil) *> (x :. y :. z :. Nil) == (x :. y :. z :. x :. y :. z :. x :. y :. z :. Nil)
--
-- prop> \x y -> Full x *> Full y == Full y
(*>) ::
  Applicative k =>
  k a
  -> k b
  -> k b
(*>) ka kb = (pure id) <$> ka <*> kb
```

For example. The `k` is `List`.

`(pure id)`'s type would be `List (a -> a)`
`<$>`'s type would be `(a -> b) -> List a -> List b`
`k a`'s type would be `List a`

1. Why `<$>`'s first param type `(a -> a)` can accept `(pure id)` which type is `List (a -> a)`
2. I don't know why `(pure id) <$> ka` can turn `1 :. 2 :. 3 :. Nil` into `id :. id :. id :. Nil`

Could someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of `pure` is only used in the context of the `(->) a` instance of `Applicative`. [Indeed <sup>[src]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1092):

> ```
> instance Applicative ((->) r) where
>     pure = const
>     (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
>     liftA2 q f g x = q (f x) (g x)
> ```

This thus means that `pure id` is equivalent here to `const id`. It might have been better to use `const id` instead.

The reason it will choose `(->) r`, *only* for the scope of `pure id`, that is an important aspect, is because `fmap` (or `<$>`) thus need a function at the left side. The only way to achieve that is to let `pure id` work with the `instance Applicative (->) r`.

But it is important to stress that the instance it picks for the applicative of `pure` has nothing to do with the `Applicative k` that will pick for `<$>` and `<*>`.

We use `const id`, to use return `id`, regardless of the item in the list, we return `id`. It would thus probably have been more clear with:

```
(*>) :: Applicative k => k a -> k b -> k b
(*>) ka kb = const id <$> ka <*> kb
```

or simpler:

```
(*>) :: Applicative k => k a -> k b -> k b
(*>) ka kb = (id <$ ka) <*> kb
```

Comment: While normally I don't comment on redundant parenthesis, this is a case that's 100% intended to work the way it does. All the Applicative operators are infixl 4, and `<|>` is infixl 3. This was specifically chosen so that Applicative/Alternative parsers can be written without parenthesis for the parsing operators. I think the use of these operators without extra parenthesis is as worth committing to memory as the use of arithmetic without extra parenthesis.